# which of the following statement are true?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

My attempts ; i take f(n) = sin(n)/n  if  i  take this in the form 
f(t) = sint/t, then it will satisfied  the all   above condition  that is 
sequence will be bounded and convergent  and series will also be convergent
 because

sinx/x= (1/x)(x- x^3/3! +x^5/5! +......is convergent

from my point of view all option a) ,option b) and option c) all are correct,,

as far  im very weak in real analysis .whethear my answer is correct or not,,,im very confused and pliz tell me the solution

Comment: Yes, (a),(b),(c) are all correct.

Comment: $f(n)=\frac{\sin(n)}{n}$ is just one among *many* possible functions satisfying the hypotheses.  It just so happens that (*according to you*) all three of the statements are true *for that specific function* however that is merely one example.  It asks you to say which of the conditions are true *for* **all** *functions* which satisfy the hypotheses, not just *for some* functions which satisfy the hypotheses.

Comment: @quasi (a) is wrong , take for instance $f(x)=1$.

Comment: Ok, yes, I was wrong. But not because of $f(x)=1$.

Comment: @Ahmad Not quite that counterexample, but indeed (a) may not be true (and thus (b) and (c) as well).

Comment: (c) is true by the integral test of convergence , which stays that $\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} f(t) dt $ and $\sum \limits_{t=1}^{\infty} f(t) $ converges together or diverges together.

Comment: @Ahmad "which says that [...] if $f$ is monotone".

Comment: (a),(b),(c) are all incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

For $(a)$, construct a function (first draw it) which spikes upwards to height $n$ at each positive integer value of $n$, but for which the spikes get thinner and thinner so that the sum of the areas of the spikes converges.

The same example will kill $(b)$ and $(c)$.

Answer (score 3):

To give an example of what the other answer is talking about, consider the piece-wise function that is $0$ except near the integers where it's graph raises up to form triangles of height $n$. If the length base of the triangle at $n$ is given by $\frac{1}{n^3}$, then the area of each triangle is $\frac{1}{2n^2}$ and so the integral is $\frac{\pi^2}{12}$ by a well-known theorem.

However, $f(n)=n$ so none of the possibilities hold.

---

If you're having trouble picturing this, let me give you drawing instructions

1. Draw a horizontal line at $x=0$. For most of the real line, the value of the function will be $0$.
2. Put a dot at $(n,n)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We want our function to satisfy $f(n)=n$ so that it violates a-c
3. Put a dot at $(0.5, 0)$ and $(1.5,0)$ and erase the line between them. Instead, connect those two points to the point at $(1,1)$ to form a triangle shape (missing the bottom).
4. Do the same with the pair of points $(2-\frac{1}{16}, 0)$ and $(2+\frac{1}{16},0)$.
5. Do the same with the pair of points $(3-\frac{1}{54}, 0)$ and $(3+\frac{1}{54},0)$.
6. For every $n$, do the same with $(n-\frac{1}{2n^3},0)$ and $(n+\frac{1}{2n^3},0)$

You'll probably struggle to actually draw this due to precision issues, but if you get fine grid paper you can likely draw two of the triangles. Hopefully the construction that you would follow is clear.

Comment: That's helpful. It's critical that the spikes are thin, so having zero values except in the thinner and thinner spike intervals is key.

Comment: im not getting..... Can u show me the graph? @ stella biderman

Comment: @legohlegoh I am on my phone and don't have the ability to make a graphic, but I can give you drawing instructions. I'll edit my answer to include that

Comment: ok ......thank u so much@stella biderman

Comment: @legohlegoh I have done so. I also made a minor modification to the function because for unimportant reasons the function I originally described doesn't exist. However, my general intent was correct. Hopefully these instructions will make what's going on clearer.

Comment: once again thank u so much ......i have draw the graph,,i got my answer @stella Biderman,,,vote up u now,,

Comment: @legohlegoh Thank you. If you feel like your question has been answered, you should accept the answer that best answers your question by pressing the checkmark button underneath the voting arrows.

Comment: i have done it @stella biderman